# Mongodb-community error homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I've been having this error while running `brew services start mongodb-community`

```
mongodb-community error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

I have tried re installing home brew, mongodb and a slew of other solutions but nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hello so running `sudo brew services start mongodb-community` fixed it after stopping mongodb.

Comment: Adding sudo worked for me as well. But it wasn't the case before. Without using the sudo and I started the service and checked for the `brew services list`, I get the following status. `mongodb-community error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist`. I am wondering this has some permission to add in the pList. But not sure how. Looking for help.

Comment: can anyone expain why is it worked? I tried to follow the doc but it was not working properly. But after doing this it worked!!

Comment: This worked for me as well. I'm also getting the same status as @fredrickcyril

Comment: `sudo brew services start mongodb-community`  .

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Finally found the error in `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` which indicated that my database files in `/usr/local/var/mongodb` were too old (version 4.2) for this version of mongodb (version 4.4). Since I didn't need those files, I deleted them, and mongodb started up fine. Read your logs, they will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: After 30 mins of trying, this worked for me so thanks. If you previously had the original mongod homebrew installation (like me) this is likely to be your issue.

Comment: Error message for reference: "This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}"

Comment: This worked for me also.  I deleted my old database files from 2017 (mongo ver3?), and allowed mongodb-community to startup with it's default files (maybe I uninstalled and reinstalled mongo to get the default db files in there).  Note that for latest macos, the default db folder is no longer /data/db.

Answer (score 3):

Hello just debugged a similiar problem.  If you attempt to run mongodb with root it shows error and the problem is likely a file permission problem.

You can confirm where (directory may vary this is the default): show mongo log with
`cat /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

You are most likely seeing a "Permission denied" error on a file. (mine was for a bunch of files).

You will need to run `chown` on those files:

`chown -R <login> /usr/local/var/mongodb`

should solve it.

You can verify by running
`ls -la <directory>` and verifying everything is now owned by your login user.

Answer (score 2):

try to delete folder "dbPath", to delete that, look at your config to get the path like this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true
```

in my Case is `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb`

now you need to folow this commands:

```
$cd /opt/homebrew/var

$rm mongodb

$mkdir mongodb
```

then:

```
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error might be that you forgot to enable the backwards-incompatible features of your old version. This might happen if you updated several versions one after the other. For example, if you wanted to migrate from 3.2 to 3.6, you would have to install all intermediate versions (in this case, 3.4), and for each of them you would have to enable the "backwards-incompatible 3.4 features" *before* installing the next version (in this case, 3.6), using this command:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

(as per instructions in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/, for example). If you forgot to do that Version 3.6 would not start, showing in the log file (/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log) the notice "* IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details."

Answer (score 1):

I did **stop** `sudo brew services stop mongodb-community` and then **start** `sudo brew services start mongodb-community`, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for 2 hours solving this problem. The problem was with an unexpected token in mongod.conf file, that made the mongodb-community@4.2 to not to start .

To track the issue open the `.plist` file look at the output log file location, you can find it after `StandardErrorPath` key.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
https://blog.codewithdan.com/installing-mongodb-on-mac-catalina-using-homebrew/
I followed this to create a data/db folder under /System/Volumes/Data
and updated the path in /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf for the variable 'dbPath:'

Make sure the user and user permissions (The user who creates this file is the same user who runs the brew service for Mongo)

Still my services haven't started. I got the error when I run 'brew services list'

Same error mentioned above on this issue.

When I checked /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

It Failed to unlink /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock this file.

Please refer the following link to solve this.(Just delete that .sock file)

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-when-start-mongo-db-on-macos/

Then, I made sure the permissions for data/db are good

d-wx--x--x   3 name  wheel    96 Mar 22 11:20 data

Then stopped the brew services for mongo and started again.
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to Rob Lopez / Craig Eddy's answer, here's what worked for me on macOS ventura 13, using mongodb-community@6.0 with homebrew:

I was getting the similar error after running `brew services start mongodb-community`

```
Name              Status        File
mongodb-community error  25600 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

It always helps to check the logs using `cat /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

In my case, looks like the last line states the problem `"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /usr/local/var/mongodb"`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-03T14:30:42.768+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-03T14:30:42.769+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-03T14:30:42.769+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-06-03T14:30:42.770+08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /usr/local/var/mongodb"}}
```

Btw, I tried using `sudo brew services start mongodb-community` and it worked but also got a warning that it's not recommended.

So I tried changing the permissions of `/usr/local/var/mongodb` with this command and this solved the error:

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Just an addtl info:

- **chown:** command used to change the ownership of files and directories in Unix-like operating systems. The chown command allows you to specify a new owner for a given file or directory.
- **-R:** It is an option for the chown command that stands for "recursive." When used, it instructs chown to operate recursively, changing the ownership of all files and directories within the specified directory and its subdirectories.
- **id -un:** This is a command substitution enclosed within backticks. It executes the id -un command and substitutes its output as part of the overall command. The id -un command is used to retrieve the username of the current user. So, in this context, it fetches the username of the user executing the sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

finally got it to work again as non-root user.

1. `brew services stop mongodb-community` or `sudo brew services stop mongodb-community`
2. `rm /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`
3. `brew services start mongodb-community`
4. `cat /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` and look for any file and/or access errors
5. fix the error (e.g. if the file or directory belongs to root, delete it, or change the owner)
6. try restart `brew services start mongodb-community`
7. `cat /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` and look for any file and/or access errors again
8. `brew services stop mongodb-community`
9. fix the errors again
10. GOTO 6

Loop until all errors are gone from /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log